# Unexpected behavior with PerlIO::encoding

Tags: windows, perl, encoding, io, fallback

When I run this script I get 8 lines of output instead of 2.

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.1;

use PerlIO::encoding;
use Encode qw(:fallbacks);
$PerlIO::encoding::fallback = Encode::FB_HTMLCREF;
binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(cp850)";

say "TEST";
say "Hell\x{263a}\x{263b}llo.txt";
```

Output:

```
# TEST
# TEST
# Hell&#9786;&#9787;llo.txt
# TEST
# Hell&#9786;&#9787;llo.txt
# TEST
# Hell&#9786;&#9787;llo.txt
#
```

Why does this script output so many lines?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: confirmed on perl 5.18.2, the same happens with other encodings like `utf8` as well. It seems very much to be a `FB_HTMLCREF` thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [a really old bug: RT#40401](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=40401).  [RT#29720](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=29720) is probably the same bug, which makes it almost 10 years old.  (And that's just when it was reported; I'd guess the bug dates back to when `$PerlIO::encoding::fallback` was first implemented.)